# How to show a progress bar while loading a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list, progress-bar, list-comprehension

Thanks in advance for your support.
I recently discovered the `Progress` module and have being playing with it. It's fairly simple for almost anything... til I decided to try with a list comprehension.
Is there a way for this? I mean, the usual kind of code for these progress bar are like:

```
from progress.bar import ChargingBar

bar = ChargingBar('Some text like Loading...', cant_of_iterations)
for iteration in some_cycle:
    --code--
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Thing is, how to use this with a List Comprehension? I don't feel like putting that bar.next() inside the LC (or, at least, don't know how...).

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't do it, because **a list comprehension should not have any side effect** (a list comprehension returns a list and that's all). Obvioulsy, drawing a progress bar *is* a side effect.

Furthermore, if you have a progress bar, I suppose that the process is rather slow: the list comprehension won't (probably) perform better than the regular loop.

So: DON'T DO IT.

---

You've been warned... but since you have asked the question, let's try with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [sum(range(i**3)) for i in range(100)]
>>> L
[0, 0, 28, 351, 2016, ..., 416485546128, 442920719836, 470739589551]
```

If I convert this to a regular loop, I can use the `progress` module:

```
from progress.bar import ChargingBar

L = []
bar = ChargingBar('Loading...')
for i in range(100):
    L.append(sum(range(i**3)))
    bar.next()
bar.finish()

print(L)
```

Output:

```
Loading... ████████████████████████████████ 100%
[0, 0, 28, 351, 2016, ..., 416485546128, 442920719836, 470739589551]
```

Now, I use a little trick to make the same with my list comprehension:

```
from progress.bar import ChargingBar

bar = ChargingBar('Loading...')
L = [sum(range(i**3)) for i in range(100) if not bar.next()]
bar.finish()
print(L)
```

Output:

```
Loading... ████████████████████████████████ 100%
[0, 0, 28, 351, 2016, ..., 416485546128, 442920719836, 470739589551]
```

The trick is easy to understand: `bar.next()` is evaluated on every iteration (the bar progresses) and returns `None`. In a boolean context, `None` is `False`:

```
>>> bool(None)
False
```

Hence, `not bar.next()` is `True` and the list is not filtered (`[... for ... if True]` is identical to `[... for ...]`).

Again, don't do it.